# AzerothCore docker install: DB fails with "Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown"

Tags: mysql, docker, innodb, docker-desktop, azerothcore

When tryint to install [AzerothCore with Docker](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/install-with-docker) I had the following error to my `ac-database` container:

```
[ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.29, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
[ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
[ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
[ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by doing a **factory reset** of my Docker Desktop application first and then installing AC again.

**NOTE: This will delete all your data from any existing Docker containers**

- Select the Docker menu whale menu and then Troubleshoot
- Select the Troubleshoot icon near the top-right corner of Docker Dashboard
- **Reset to factory defaults**

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given "Upgrade after crash" isn't supported. And "redo log was MySQL 5.7.33", go back so it isn't an upgrade and shutdown without a crash:

1. Start a mysql:5.7.33 container on the same data dir.
2. Cleanly shutdown the container (no force shutdowns, just leave it naturally finish).
3. start your MySQL 8.0.25 container on the same datadir.